# Binding multiple model properties to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

my model looks something like:

```
 public class ProductDto
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

My list box is bind to Products property, which is a List of product models.
What I'm trying to do, is to bind Description name and price properties in the listbox, and show them as a grid with 3 columns so to speak.

```
ProductName ProductDescription Price
prod1       desc1              15
prod2       desc2              20

<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="105" Margin="332,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="273" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" Name="CurrentOrderItems">
        </ListBox>
```

What is the way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this,

```
<ListView Name="CurrentOrderItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="1" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProductName }" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="2" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProductDescription }" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="3" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Price}" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```